# Thruk Reporting module SLA calculation

Tags: monitoring, nagios, thruk

Can you explain me how are calculated the SLA made by Thruk reporting module ?
I use it to provide KPIs to my customer and he ask me the calculation rules.
Thanks by advance.

Comment: What have you done so far to try and figure it out yourself?

Comment: Hello newcomers, this site is more about programming and your question is more suitable for https://serverfault.com/ general A&Q.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.